# Find most common character in PHP String

Tags: php

I am looking for the most efficient way to find the most common character in a php string.

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"aaaaabcaab"
```

The result should be stored in the variable $total.

So in this case $total should be equal to `a`

Comment: Split the string, `array_count_values`…

Comment: What should happen in the event of a tie such as `aabb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function,

```
function getHighest($str){
    $str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);//Trims all the spaces in the string
    $arr = str_split(count_chars($str.trim($str), 3));
    $hStr = "";
    $occ = 0;

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $oc = substr_count ($str, $value);
        if($occ < $oc){
            $hStr = $value;
            $occ = $oc;
        }
    }

    return $hStr;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Te easiest way to achieve this is:

```
// split the string per character and count the number of occurrences
$totals = array_count_values( str_split( 'fcaaaaabcaab' ) );

// sort the totals so that the most frequent letter is first
arsort( $totals );

// show which letter occurred the most frequently
echo array_keys( $totals )[0];

// output
a
```

One thing to consider is what happens in the event of a tie:

```
// split the string per character and count the number of occurrences
$totals = array_count_values( str_split( 'paabb' ) );

// sort the totals so that the most frequent letter is first
arsort( $totals );

// show all letters and their frequency
print_r( $totals );

// output
Array
(
    [b] => 2
    [a] => 2
    [p] => 1
)
```

Comment: ...so your second snippet should include an `array_filter()` with a `use()` value derived from `max()` and no need to `arsort()`, right?

Comment: As for your first snippet, wouldn't you rather use `key($totals)`?

Comment: @mickmackusa My answer was written over 2 years ago. If I edit it then OP will never know. I recommend writing your own answer with your suggestions.

Comment: SO answers are **never** a one-to-one interaction between the OP and the volunteer. Every page is a one-to-many relationship where thousands of future researchers will draw direct and indirect knowledge from posted insights. Not only will people continually read and learn from your snippets, they are also likely to extract coding habits/styling -- this is why high rep volunteers such as yourself also need to be concerned with fine details like performance, directness, clarity, and PSR coding standards. Keep an eye on the big picture. Wouldn't you prefer the same treatment as a researcher?

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm aware of the future value of my post. Sometimes when something is presented in a less-than-optimal way it causes the reader to have an aha moment and think outside the box for their own problem. The fact that there are hundreds of way to achieve the same task is the beauty of programming. Trying to pigeonhole a solution into perfection is not always the goal.